# Postgres query - return flattened JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following working query:

```
const getPromos = async (limit = 10, site: string, branch: string) => {
    const query = `SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'id', p.id,
        'description', p.description,
        'discounted_price', p.discounted_price,
        'items', jsonb_agg((i.id, i.price, i.title))
    )
    FROM promotions p
    INNER JOIN promotion_items pi ON p.id = pi.promotion_id
    INNER JOIN items i ON pi.item_code = i.item_code WHERE site_id = ${site} and store_id = ${branch}
    GROUP BY p.id LIMIT ${limit}`;
    return await db.query(query);
};
```

The issue is simple - each item (in this example - promotion) is returned with an object that wraps it - named `json_build_object`. I don't want any object to wrap my promotions - just like this:

```
[{id:1, .... items: [...items here...]}, {id:2, .... items: [...items here...]}]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, seems more like the host language or how you use it somehow adds that wrapping based on the column name. [Edit] the question and tag the host language and framework (if any). And note, that 9.5 is out of support for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result directly from the query when you aggregate the resultset using `jsonb_agg` (like `items` further down the query).

```sql
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
        'id', p.id,
        'description', p.description,
        'discounted_price', p.discounted_price,
        'items', jsonb_agg((i.id, i.price, i.title))
    ))
--- the rest of your query
```